# Тип, возвращаемый функцией main

Tags: c++

Во многих примерах кода на сайте встречаются как записи вида `void main()`, так и `int main()` для главной функции программы.

Какой из них правильный и в чём вообще разница?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стандарт языка [требует обязательного наличия](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main) двух возможных реализаций:

- ```
  int main()
  ```
- ```
  int main(int, char**)
  ```

То есть в обоих случаях возвращаемым типом является `int`. Однако, разрешается существование и дополнительных вариантов в том или ином компиляторе:

> Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

Таким образом, вариант, возвращающий `int` является переносимым между разными реализациями компиляторов, а `void` к таковым не относится. Но в частности `void main()` поддерживается компилятором *Microsoft Visual C++*.

Возвращаемое значение `main` в общем случае говорит об успешности работы программы. Если всё прошло хорошо, то возвращается ноль - `return 0;`; иначе следует вернуть какое-то другое целочисленное значение, которое можно обработать на стороне, вызвавшей программу. Разрешается явно не писать `return 0;` в `main`. В таком случае, при выходе из функции `0` будет подразумеваться. Аналогичное поведение распространяется и на `void` вариант от MS. Но если в случае с `int` код возврата можно вернуть явно через `return`, то с `void main()` такой вариант уже [не пройдет](http://rextester.com/YWBE66879):

> ```
> error C2562: 'main': 'void' function returning a value
> ```

Правда, вместо этого [можно использовать](http://rextester.com/NEMZT62605) функцию `exit(0)`, которая прерывает выполнение программы и возвращает переданный код вызывающей стороне.

Comment: к теме не относится, но есть еще 3-я реализация `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);` envp - массив переменных среды

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема является проблемой линковщика, а не компилятора.

Нужно понимать, что main является `_cdecl` функцией, т.е. функции всёравно сколько параметров, потому что, опорная библиотека будет иметь примерно такой вид

```
push ecx; argv
push eax; argc
call _main
pop ecx
pop ecx
push eax ; Код возрата
call _exit ; И на выход с кодом возврата
```

Т.е. фактически если ф-ция будет `int main()` -  стек не испортится, просто функция не увидит argv и argc. А функция `void main(int argc, int argv)` получит оба параметра.

Так как опора идет на сигнатуру _main, то на эту сигнатуру можно посадить любую функцию, которая или не имеет параметров, или имеет метку _cdecl (если это не запретит компилятор). Для получения такой сигнатуры нужно указать что используются страрые сигнатуры, делается это указанием `extern "C"` (это указание присутствует в стандартных библиотеках, благодаря которым main и срабатывает). Т.е. могут прокатить виды `extern "C" int _cdecl main(...); int _cdecl main(...){}` а так же аналогично `void main()`, `int main(int argc)` и даже `long _cdecl main(...);`, `int _cdecl main(int argc, char** argv, int secparam1, int secparam2, int secparam3)`

Теперь о возвращаемом типе. Опорная библиотека ожидает, что в eax прийдет результат. При использовании `void` - программа может вернуть "мусор", который вернётся из eax, с этой точки зрения `int main()` лучше. Но последнее время, код возврата программы нигде не анализируется, поэтому если ф-ция вернула "мусор"  - это с большой вероятностью ни на что не повлияет.

Если вы пишите под батник, или под програмный комплекс (инсталятор например) , где проверяется код возврата - то нужно писать `int main()` и возвращать нужные значения.

Так же, есть функции `exit` `terminate`, и есть обработчики исключений, которые прерыват программу в обход `main` - если программа прерывается всегда "насильно" - то возвращаемый тип перестаёт играть свою роль.

Comment: Вопрос в возвращаемом типе, а не о принимаемых аргументах. К томе же cdecl это соглашения для конкретной архитектуры и к стандарту языка вообще не имеет отношения.

Comment: Хорошо. Добавлю.