# Чем отличаются функции начинающиеся с void от int в Си?

Tags: c

Одни начинают функции с `int`, другие с `void`. 
Чем вот этот вариант ... :

```
int increaser(int* x) //используем указатель
{

 (*x)++;
 //return (*x);

};
```

... отличается от этого ? :

```
void increaser(int* x) //используем указатель
{

 (*x)++;
 //return (*x);

};
```

Слышала (из курса от Специалиста), что `void` используют при программировании драйверов.

Comment: Первый вариант, по-хорошему, не должен бы компилироваться: сказано, что функция возвращает целое число, но ни одного `return` при этом в теле нет. `main` же случай особый, но его полная сигнатура по-хорошему включает возврат int (код выхода) и приём массива строк (аргументов командной строки) в виде числа элементов и указателя на нулевой из них. Но из-за исторически сложившегося разброда инструменты могут стерпеть и ряд других записей.

Comment: Первый вариант не будет компилироваться.

Comment: void [функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) в Си соответствуют [подпрограммам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0) (исторически они появились до функций) в других языках. Попробуйте почитать в вике (по ссылкам). По сути разница в том, что основным назначением функции (по крайней мере к этому стоит стремиться) является возврат чистого результата, а подпрограммы -- побочные эффекты

Comment: void-функция не возвращает значение. Вот и всё. Например, они могут что то изменять по ссылке, или отображать что то пользователю. С драйверами это вообще никак не связано.

Comment: @D-side возврат значения из функции может быть и другими средствами, отличными от `return`, быть обеспечен, поэтому здесь всего лишь предупреждение, а не ошибка.

Comment: @Эникейщик будет.

Comment: @alexolut портируемо или через "контролируемый UB"/особенности платформы? :)

Comment: @D-side платформозависимо. По стандарту С++ завершение функции, возвращающей что-то отличное от `void` - это UB. Но здесь C и действуют немного [другие правила](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735101/3240681).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая функция, обязательно требует чтобы из нее был произведен возврат данных типа int, любой иной тип или вообще игнорирования возврата значение, вызовет ошибку.

Вторая функция, не требует чтобы вы что-то возвращали, возврат при этом допустим, но это предположительно — **плохой** тон. Что те , что иные функции, используются одинаково в программировании драйверов. С типами на столь низком уровне работают серьёзно.

Comment: При попытке возврата не будет никакой ошибки. Оператор return является принудительным завершением процедуры

Comment: Не учел это, Благодарю.

Comment: Игнорирование возврата для функции с возвращаемым значением не вызовет ошибку (если конечно не включить обработку предупреждений как ошибок).

Answer (score 1):

Первая функция возвращает значения типа int (32битное целое) с которым можно в дальнейшем работать, вторая функция ничего не возвращает (слышал как некоторые в шутку называют тип void пустышкой)

Comment: С Си не соскучишься.... Если void пустышка, то зачем в книгах проскальзывают примеры с main функцией с использованием void ?

Comment: @Tanya разнотипные функции main используются исключительно линкером для установки entry point с ОС.

Comment: @Tanya по поводу `main` есть [вопрос/ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/794522/176217).

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример:

```
int incr1(int *p)
{
    ++(*p);
    return *p;
}
void incr2(int* p)
{
    ++(*p);
}

int main()
{   
    int m[] = {1,2, 3};
    m[0]  += incr1(m); // выражение справа возвращает целое  m[0] которое равен 2
    //тогда прибавив  к m[0]  еще и это значение, получим m[0] == 4
    cout << m[0] <<endl;
    // а другой функцией можем только инкремент осуществлять
    incr2(m);
    // и не можем это присвоить чему то
    // просто наращиваем m[0] еще на  единицу
    cout << m[0]; // 5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так то, речь про Си (без плюсов)