# Можно ли соединить два multiset в один multiset с помощью каких-либо функций?

Tags: c++, multiset

Например у меня есть два **multiset< int > a, b;** и я хочу воссоединить их в один **multiset< int > c;** Можно ли это сделать? Если можно то пожалуйста напишите пример. Спасибо заранее :)

Comment: В зависимости от того, насколько нужна скорость. И нужны ли контейнеры a и b. Есть просто merge (с++17) `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/merge`, работает за nlog(n + m). Хорош, если a и b больше не нужны и один из контейнеров сильно больше другого. Иначе можно сделать за n + m. Дело в том, что если строить multiset из у порядочного массива, он строится линейно от размера массива. Взять например конструктор `template< class InputIterator >
multiset( InputIterator first, InputIterator last) `

Comment: Остаётся только написать класс итератора, который принимает 2 диапазона итераторов с обоих multiset, но мержит их не сразу, а по ходу вызова операторов ++ и * двигает и возвращает наибольшее значение. Сменить 2 отсортированных массива О (n + m)

Comment: Если лень писать итератор, то можно с помощью std::merge смержить 2 multiset сначала в vector, и в конструктор multiset передавать vector.begin(), vector.end()

Comment: Функции merge вполне достаточно для моих целей и оказался легок в использовании, а контейнеры a и b мне нужны для дальнейшего использования. Спасибо огромное)

Comment: `merge` - не самый эффективный и не самый короткий в смысле текста способ. Но, конечно, если устраивает, то никаких вопросов :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `insert` контейнера `multiset` умеет вставлять в него произвольные *диапазоны* элементов, задаваемые начальным и конечным итератором. Но такая вставка рассчитана но более общий случай: произвольный, никак не упорядоченный диапазон.

В вашем же случае оба `multiset` упорядочены по тому же компаратору. В такой ситуации заманчиво было бы воспользоваться этой упорядоченностью для повышения эффективности вставки. Такую возможность предоставляет метод `insert` для вставки одного элемента с *хинтом*. Если новый элемент вставляется в multiset непосредственно перед хинт-позицией, то вставка выполняется за амортизированное *константное* время. В простейшем виде это будет выглядеть так

```
multiset<int> c = a;

auto it_hint = c.begin();
for (const int &src : b)
{
  it_hint = c.insert(it_hint, src);
  ++it_hint;
}
```

Но еще лучше было бы применить обычный алгоритм слияния двух упорядоченных последовательностей

```
multiset<int> c;
std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(c, c.end()));
```

Каков будет эффект от такой оптимизации - зависит от тяжести единичной операции сравнения, повторяемости элементов multiset, взаимного распределения элементов двух исходных наборов, от накладных расходов, определяемых качеством реализации, и т.п. Я замечаю, что доступные мне стандартные реализации `std::merge` (или `std::insert_iterator`?) где-то тратят на что-то время и вариант с `std::merge` оказывается немножко медленнее варианта с прямым `insert`.

Но достаточно ту же идею реализовать явно

```
void my_merge(const S& a, const S& b, S& c)
{
  auto ita = a.begin(), itae = a.end();
  auto itb = b.begin(), itbe = b.end();
  auto itce = c.end();

  if (ita != itae && itb != itbe)
    do
      if (*ita <= *itb)
      {
        c.insert(itce, *ita);
        if (++ita == itae)
          break;
      }
      else
      {
        c.insert(itce, *itb);
        if (++itb == itbe)
          break;
      }
    while (true);

  for (; ita != itae; ++ita)
    c.insert(itce, *ita);

  for (; itb != itbe; ++itb)
    c.insert(itce, *itb);
}
```

как вариант со слиянием начинает выигрывать уверенно в MSVC. В GCC такой вариант проигрывает при высокой вариабельности элементов multiset. Но достаточно подавить вариабельность элементов, как вариант со слиянием начинает [побеждать](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ac327f12b0fe91) и в GCC.

Алгоритмическое превосходство варианта со слиянием основано на уменьшении количества сравнений, поэтому чисто ради эксперимента интересно посмотреть, что произойдет в варианте с более "тяжелым" сравнением. Возьмем multiset из `std::array<int, 10>` с небольшой вариабельностью элементов - и вот уже вариант со слиянием [побеждает намного более явно](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6029e3b22f2691ce).

Чего тут действительно не хватает - это возможности прямой вставки в multiset без проверки правильности хинта. На эту проверку тратится время, но метода вставки, в котором multiset бы "верил джентльменам на слово", к сожалению нет. Если бы таковой имелся, то вариант со слиянием был бы очевидным и абсолютным чемпионом.

При этом, как уже сказано выше, работают все хорошо известные классические соображения для выбора алгоритма: слияние двух упорядоченных последовательностей длин `N` и `M` делается за время `O(N + M)`, а общая поэлементная вставка одной последовательности в другую делается за время `O(N * log M)`. Для последовательностей "почти одинаковой" длины выигрывает слияние, для последовательностей "очень разной" длины выигрывает вставка более короткой в более длинную.

Comment: насколько я знаю,  c.insert(b.begin(),b.end())  выполняет то же самое

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Какое именно "то же самое"? Самый оптимальный вариант - именно `std::merge`. Но `c.insert(b.begin(),b.end())` не может такого делать, ибо для `std::merge` требуется упорядоченный диапазон, а `c.insert` об упорядоченности диапазона ничего не знает. Хотя, конечно, может проверять на лету...

Comment: Не согласен, не может стандартный альгоритм быть оптимальнее  метода стандартного контейнера. Каждый метод класса использует свое внутреннее представление, и если этот метод должен использовать другие методы, чтобы быть оптимальным, или если другой альгоритм круче собственного метода, значит метод реализован не достаточно эффективно. Не думаю, что вы сомневаетесь в  хорошей реализации методов стандартного контейнера...

Comment: @Дмитрий Зиненко: О чем вы? `std::merge` всегда сам работает за `O(n + m)` и критически завязан на отсортированность входных последовательностей. Если, как обещается, вставка с хинтом `c.end()` будет проходить за `O(1)`, то весь вариант с `std::merge` дает `O(n + m)`, что является оптимальным вариантом для последовательностей "примерно одинаковой" длины.

Comment: AnT, да, вы правы, я туплю.

Comment: Ну к чему теоретические рассуждения, если конкретные результаты тайминга можно посмотреть в моем исправленном ответе? :) `merge` из приведенных вариантов хуже всего, лучше всего - `insert` без всяких подсказок. Проверено на VC++ и GCC.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы правы, `merge` проигрывает - см. мой дополненный ответ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ответ за тебя кто постить должен?

Comment: @Qwertiy, извеняюсь, я по делам отходил... О каком ответе речь? Я написал свое мнение и мне нечего добавить

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, `c=a; c.insert(b.begin(),b.end())`, который уже замерили в соседнем ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  я и без этих замеров знал что окажется быстрее, и я не был неправ. Не знаю что я мог ответить еще

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я тоже. Но почему ответ-то в комментарии вместо ответа?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Уже опровергнуто. Еще раз: вариант со слиянием - быстрее. И если в некоторой реализации вставка заведомо отсортированной последовательности оказывается *медленее* (!) вставки общей последовательности, то этого говорит лишь о кривости реализации.

Answer (score 2):

Если очень нужно именно в новый - то сначала скопировать один из исходных, а потом обычный `insert`.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    multiset<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 3 };
    multiset<int> b = { 2, 3, 4, 4 };

    multiset<int> c = a;
    c.insert(b.begin(),b.end());

    for(auto i: c)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

**Update**

Как обычно, ставим эксперимент...

Код эксперимента вкратце -

```
multiset<int> HW(const multiset<int>& a, const multiset<int>& b)
{
    multiset<int> c (a);
    c.insert(b.begin(),b.end());
    return c;
}

multiset<int> AnT(const multiset<int>& a, const multiset<int>& b)
{
    multiset<int> c = a;

    auto it_hint = c.begin();
    for (const int &src : b)
    {
        it_hint = c.insert(it_hint, src);
        ++it_hint;
    }
    return c;
}

multiset<int> AnTmerge(const multiset<int>& a, const multiset<int>& b)
{
    multiset<int> c;
    std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(c, c.end()));
    return c;
}

...

multiset<int> a;
multiset<int> b;

for(int i = 0; i < 1000'000; ++i)
{
    a.insert(rand());
    b.insert(rand());
}

multiset<int> c, d, e;

{
    muTimer mt;
    c = HW(a,b);
    mt.stop();
    cout << mt.duration() << endl;
}

{
    muTimer mt;
    d = AnT(a,b);
    mt.stop();
    cout << mt.duration() << endl;
}

{
    muTimer mt;
    e = AnTmerge(a,b);
    mt.stop();
    cout << mt.duration() << endl;
}
```

Результаты трех запусков  на VC++ 2017 на моей машине:

```
375749    385684    393137
415450    419331    442624
556450    567419    602691
```

Результаты на GCC и полный код см. [здесь](http://ideone.com/OGPIR3).

Т.е. лучше всего - обычный `insert` для диапазона, чуть-чуть хуже поэлементно с подпихиванием руками (подсказкой), и еще хуже - `merge`...

**Update 2**

Каюсь, обнаружил у себя одну [очепятку](http://ideone.com/iT59fP). Так что на самом деле результат с подсказкой оказывается немного лучшим просто вставки, но `merge` остается худшим решением... Мои извинения за небольшое введение в заблуждение.

Зато пришла в голову еще одна (реально работающая) оптимизация моего метода - копировать большее множество, а добавлять элементы из меньшего.

Comment: Harry, несущественно, но вы забыли возвращать значение из main

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Совершенно несущественно, ибо стандарт такое вполне разрешает...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan собственно, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794523/176217)